# How do I make "show in folder" open the folder with the archive selected?

Tags: lubuntu, files

I use Lubuntu, when I ask my browser or other application to show a file in a folder, it will open the folder but without that file highlighted; so I have to search the folder for it. How can I make my computer aways open the folders with the file I asked it to show me highlighted?

Comment: Maybe you can sort the files and folders date-and-time wise in your 'Downloads' folder. So you know that the last file downloaded is the first one in the folder.